# Spring Security: How to retrieve user's information in sign in?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have implemented Spring boot, with Spring security. And here is how I configure the http requests:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers( "/registeration").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/home").hasRole("USER")
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
  http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true);
}
```

So, I am trying to redirect my logged in users to the `/home` url, and here is the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model,@RequestParam Long userId) {
    model.addAttribute("user", userService.getUserById(userId));
    return "home";
}
```

But, as you see, I need to pass the `userId`, to add it as a model into my view. The problem is, I don't know how to retrieve the information of yje user before redirect, and after log in.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
        model.addAttribute("user", authentication.getPrincipal());
        return "home";
    }
```

Some good examples [here](http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security)

Comment: shouldn't i pass the result of `authentication.getPrincipal()` to the `userService.getUserById`?

Comment: @Salman as look as you've set Spring Security up correctly this is all your need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @dur.

When the user logs in, then all of his information is in to the `SecurityContextHolder`, and the targeted uri can receive the `principal`, which contains the **identity of the principal being authenticated.** which contains the username of the logged in user. So, here is the solution:

```
@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model,Principal principal) {
    final String currentUser = principal.getName();
    log.info("Logged User is:    "+ currentUser);

    model.addAttribute("user", userService.getUserByUsername(currentUser));
    return "home";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment to @Salman's answer, but I don't have the reputation to do that. what I wanted to say is that I think:

in `model.addAttribute("user", userService.getUserByUsername(currentUser));`, `userService.getUserByUsername(currentUser)` would return the same result as the injected `principal`. Therefore, `model.addAttribute("user", principal);` can work a little better.

Comment: In general it is not the same. In this case it is not clear, because OP has not shown his user model class.